# Probability of all elements of a subset being coprime

Tags: probability, divisibility

Let $S=\{1,..,n\}$ and $R \subset S$ ($|R|=k$, $k<n$) -- $R$ is a random subset of $S$. Let $m=min(R)$, and $R'=\{x-m: x \in R, x \neq m\}$, so $|R'|=k-1$.

What's the probability that $gcd(R')=1$?

EDIT:

I know that probability of $gcd(R)=1$ is $1/\zeta(k)$ when $n = \infty$ and I was wondering about this variation. When $n=\infty$, $R'$ is just a random subset of natural numbes, just like $R$ is, so in both cases elements have a uniform distribution. When $n$ is finite, elements of $R'$ don't have a uniform distribution -- for example $1 \in R'$ is more probable than $n-1 \in R'$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Inclusion-exclusion.
- Let $A$ denote the event that the elements of $R$ are coprime. For every integer $i\gt n/k$, let $a(i)=0$. For every positive integer $i\leqslant n/k$,
  $$
  a(i)=\frac{\lfloor\frac{n}i\rfloor!}{n^k\left(\lfloor\frac{n}i\rfloor-k\right)!},
  $$
  then
  $$
  P[A]=1-\sum_pa(p)+\sum_{p,q}a(pq)-\sum_{p,q,r}a(pqr)+\cdots
  $$
  where each sum is on the distinct prime numbers $p$, $q$, $r$, and so on (the sum is finite since, in fact, at most the first $\log_2(n/k)$ terms of this series are nonzero).